# Promise.all does not behave as expected

Tags: typescript

I wonder why in the below code the first console log prints 0. The second does print 1oo as expected. Can someone explain?

```
let count = 0;

async function incr(): Promise<number> {
    setTimeout(() => count++, 1);
    return count;
}

const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) promises.push(incr());
Promise.all(promises).then(async () => console.log('count = ' + count));

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('count = ' + count);
}, 100);
```

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#return_value) doesn't return a promise...

Comment: setTimeout doesn't return a promise, which you don't await anyway.

Comment: Wrapping something in an `async` function won't get awaited magically, only if it returns a promise and you use `await` on it.

Comment: I have updated the example by returning a Promise from incr(). This does not change the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your `incr` function doesn't return anything explicitly, so it returns a Promise that resolves immediately.

`Promise.all` runs in the microtask queue as soon as all Promises in the passed array resolve. So, that's what runs first - the callback passed to `Promise.all(promises).then(`.

The `setTimeout` queues a macrotask, and such tasks run much later than microtasks.

If you wanted it to log 100, do:

```js
let count = 0;

function incr() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      count++;
      resolve();
    }, 1);
  });
}

const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) promises.push(incr());
Promise.all(promises).then(async() => console.log('count = ' + count));

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('count = ' + count);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. In my case the function `incr` is give, however it in fact returns a promise. I have updated the example in the question accordingly. Still the code returns 0 for the first call.

Comment: The Promise being returned from `incr` is still being resolved immediately, before the `setTimeout` callback runs, so `count` is 0 in the `Promise.all` callback